# Bash variable calling

Tags: php, bash

so I'm translating a bash script to php.  I wrote none of the original bash and am learning php as I go.
In the bash script, I've come across something like

```
echo -en "To: \"${thisEmailName}\" <${thatEmailName}>\nFrom: \"${fromThisEmail}\" <${fromThisEmailName}>\nSubject: ..."
```

Now I think I have a grasp on what \"variable\" is doing, in my understanding it is just doing an escape character so it shows up as "variable" in the output (please tell me if I'm wrong).  But my major problem is the  as I have absolutely no idea what it is doing.

Thanks for everything in advance.

-SH

Comment: Looks like you're building an email message and making sure that the values in the assorted email headers are quoted in places that need it.  So you'll get a line like `To: "Eric Renouf" <test_email@nowhere.example>` and so forth

Comment: ah, so the < & > will actually show up in the output?

Comment: Yup, they will with that command, and that's an important part of the email header (see [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4))